# remove r workspace in ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu-12.04

folks

I just installed ubuntu R, but when I saved my R work space, it loaded automatically every time when i launch R from the terminal. This had disabled couple of functions in the package i wanted to use.

My questions is how to remove my r work space in ubuntu? any idea where the location of the file is ? 
I tried suggestions from this site: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/How-to-permanently-remove-Previously-saved-workspace-restored-td3041515.html
, but i did not really give a clear solution to it.

Best.

Comment: Did you try searching for and deleting any `*.RData` files in your working directory? (Try with `list.files()` from within R, if required).

Comment: Also, you can try starting R with `--vanilla`, as suggested in the linked post.

Comment: You could alias `R` to add on the `--no-restore`, `--no-save` or `--vanilla` options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a file called `.RData` in your working directory:

```
> getwd()
[1] "/home/rowlings"
> system("ls .RData")
.RData
```

Because it starts with a dot its not visible in the unix shell unless you do `ls -a`.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing ~/.RData

In case that is hard for you to understand, ~/ is the Unix way of saying "your home directory", and the ~/.RData file is the "default" workspace if you didn't explicitly set a different working directory.