# Where is the default .RData workspace saved in a Linux environment?

Tags: r, linux, rstudio

I am running RStudio on a compute cluster, and every time I launch an RStudio instance it immediately crashes.  I suspect there is something wrong with the workspace that loads by default.  However, I can't actually find where this workspace is stored.  How do I delete this file?

I found a hidden file named `.Rdata` in the `/usr/` directory.  But when I rename this file and boot up an instance of RStudio, the old workspace still boots up.

Comment: Is it in the working directory?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22305973/remove-r-workspace-in-ubuntu) will help. Or, since you are using RStudio, [this one](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711843-Working-Directories-and-Workspaces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the problem by renaming the folder in the RStudio-Desktop Directory:

```
~/.rstudio-desktop/sources/
```

If you're not using Linux, you can find the location of your RStudio-Desktop Directory here:

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State